# Como usar o StreamReader para ler o arquivo.txt e inserir os dados em uma List?

Tags: c#

Eu criei um programa que realiza o CRUD , sempre que eu crio, atualizo ou deleto um funcionário ele atualiza o arquivo TxT usando o StreamWriter, ao iniciar o programa estou tentando Ler esse mesmo arquivo e já inserir na List que eu criei, pra poder ter os dados de quando eu usei anteriormente, porém, do jeito que eu fiz o StreamReader ele não está colocando na List de forma correta, apesar de ler todas as linhas.

```cs
 List<Funcionarios> func = new List<Funcionarios>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Usuário\Teste.txt"))
            {
                string line;
                Funcionarios funcionario = new Funcionarios();
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    funcionario.nome = sr.ReadLine();
                    funcionario.matricula = sr.ReadLine();
                    funcionario.cargo = sr.ReadLine();
                    func.Add(funcionario);
                }
```

Ai está a parte do código que lê o arquivo e deveria armazenar na List func.

Comment: tenta instanciar o `funcionario` dentro da instrução while

Comment: ainda não foi, quando eu salvo algo dentro do arquivo .txt e escolho a opção de Listar no programa aparece somente o cargo e a matrícula do funcionário, oq n faz sentido já q eu coloquei 3 informações e no código estou lendo as três..

Comment: O que exatamente você quer dizer com: "ele não está colocando na List de forma correta". Apresente um exemplo do seu arquivo de texto... Ao invés de colocar cada informação em uma linha, não seria mais adequado escrever uma linha por funcionário e separar os valores por algum marcador? ex.: `;`

Comment: não faz sentido você usar essa forma de escrita no documento (pois o sr.readLine() tambem está sendo um parâmetro de busca). O ideal seria você cadastrar uma linha inteira usando separadores específicos (string1 - string2 - string3). E na hora de usar o readLine(), fazer um split para colocar essas string em cada parametro do objeto

Comment: http://prntscr.com/p0twqb Esse foi o funcionário que eu salvei.  http://prntscr.com/p0tx1m ele ficou salvo desta forma no arquivo .txt       porém ao abrir o programa novamente e pedir para ele listar, ele listou isso: http://prntscr.com/p0txfj

Comment: Walter como eu faria desta forma? Utilizando o split? Eu mudei para colocar todos os dados sobre o funcionário em uma linha, e separei os dados por ";" só não consegui fazer o StreamReader armazenar em cada objeto

Comment: @FuriosG Edite a pergunta e apresente o seu código atualizado

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, pesquisei sobre Split e arrumei meu código da forma que eu desejava.

Answer (score 1):

O seu principal erro está em ler uma linha para cada atribuição que está fazendo. Toda vez que você executa o `sr.ReadLine();`, está lendo e movendo o "cursor" para a próxima linha.

Mesmo no seu cenário original onde cada valor está em uma linha, quando você faz a declaração while `((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)`, já está lendo, armazenando e direcionando para a próxima linha... por isso quando executa o trecho de código dentro do loop você não está trabalhando no intervalo esperado.

Levando em consideração seguinte estrutura do seu arquivo de texto como no exemplo abaixo:

```
Nome do Primeiro Funcionário;0001;Diretor
Nome do Segundo Funcionário;0002;Gerente
Nome do Terceiro Funcionário;0003;Operador
Nome do Quarto Funcionário;0004;Auxiliar
```

Você pode ler cada linha e utilizar o split para definir o valor para cada uma das propriedades.

```
List<Funcionario> listaFuncionarios = new List<Funcionario>();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\Funcionarios.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var dadosFuncionario = line.Split(';');
        Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario
        {
            Nome = dadosFuncionario[0],
            Matricula = dadosFuncionario[1],                        
            Cargo = dadosFuncionario[2]
        };

        listaFuncionarios.Add(funcionario);
    }
}
```

Comment: @furiosg ficou claro onde você estava errando?

Comment: Ficou sim, muito obrigado, já tinha utilizado o split e funcionou certinho!!